# A Proof relating to the Disjunctive normal form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Here is a problem from Kenneth Rosen's *[Discrete Mathematics and its Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072899050), Section 1.3*

> Suppose that a truth table in $n$ propositional variables is specified.
>   Show that a compound proposition with this truth table can be formed
>   by taking the disjunction of conjunctions of the variables or their
>   negations, with one conjunction included for each combination of
>   values for which the compound proposition is true. The resulting
>   compound proposition is said to be disjunctive normal form.

I have been stuck in this question for quite some time and I would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

This is a homework problem and I am not expecting a complete answer. However, what I would like is to get a feel of what a Disjunctive Normal form is. I have been looking it up on the internet but no explanation is a good enough explanation for me. I would really appreciate an explanation.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It doesn't seem stated quite right as a question.  If you have a wff with at least three-variables like ApAqr (I use Polish notation), then you have conjunctions like KKpqr, which means you've used two conjunctions.  If the author wants to introduce an n-ary conjuction preferably would make clear how to do that first, and show how they can get derived from the binary conjunction connective that you start with.

Answer (score 2):

This example is for explanation of what a Disjunctive Normal form is, 
On purpose i don't simplify the resulting formula, 
The question is about homework and it should stay homework.

suppose you have the truth table:

```
P  Q    Value
T  T      T
T  F      T
F  T      F
F  F      T
```

and you want to transform that into a formula in the Disjunctive Normal form.

First add to the true values the formula that makes that row valid

> P  Q    Value   formula
>      T  T      T     $ (P \land Q )$
>      T  F      T     $ (P \land \neg Q )$
>      F  T      F     ------------------ (this value is false so don't mention formula)
>      F  F      T     $ (\neg P \land \neg Q )$

(sorry had some problems with the layout)

and then or them together

$ (P \land Q ) \lor (P \land \neg Q ) \lor (\neg P \land \neg Q ) $

And this formula is in Disjunctive Normal form.

notice this formula can be simplified but that is out of scope for this answer, see
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form
and 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map
for that.

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Show that ¬ and ∧ form a functionally complete collection
of logical operators. [Hint: First use a De Morgan
law to show that p ∨ q is logically equivalent to
¬(¬p ∧ ¬q)